# Reading Opus File, searching for Encoded-Audio Data

Tags: c++, file, audio, opus

I want to get the Encoded Opus-Audio Data without performing the decoding process. I have written functions using the RFCs to read Ogg-pages and the Opus-header and Opus-Tags. I also could identify the next Ogg-page, but where does the Opus-data packet start, especially where is the Opus-TOC header?
Does it start right after the OGG-Packet, is is part of the Ogg-Packet?

Thanks.

Comment: Find attached the identified Ogg-Page (Hex-Values) 4F 67 67 53 is the identifier for OggS:

`code` 4F 67 67 53 00 00 80 BB 00 00 00 00 00 00 68 BF 8D 6A 02 00 00 00 AF 34 54 3F 36 FF 4B CD D0 D1 D2 E0 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E7 E8 E6 FF 53 DE E8 F1 FF 34 DE D9 DA DA FF 46 DB D8 D9 FB D9 DB E0 E1 E6 E4 E3 E5 E3 E3 FC`code`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had some error in calculating the length of the OggS-Page. Once I solved this, the Opus TOC-Header was the next byte within the stream.